# Detect address bar changes firefox android extension

Tags: android, firefox-addon, addeventlistener

I'm working on a firefox for android addon, and there is a function that i need to be fired every time a new page (tab) is loaded: a new tab is opened or the address of the current tab changes. I tried to use listener ("load"/"tabSelect") but the first one didn't work and the second doesn't detect the address bar changes:

```
    window.BrowserApp.deck.addEventListener("load", onPageLoad, true);
```

Should I add more than one listener? and I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example%3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes), but it doesn't work for firefox for android. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why "load" is not working for you. I do know that "load" is sometimes not called, when loading a page from back/forward session history for example. To work around that, you could try using the "pageshow" event. That will be called for any page-change.

For more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Mobile